# Spring Boot + FreeMarker + RestController loading templates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I'm using FreeMarker as a way to construct strings that are properties of a POJO I put on the wire as a response to a REST request. I've added Freemarker to the project's Maven pom and I can inject the configuration in to my services, though I have to do one peculiar thing in order to get the classloader to find my templates.

```
     private Template getTemplate() throws Exception {
        configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/template/");

        Template temp = configuration.getTemplate("test.ftl");

        return temp;
    }
```

Is there a cleaner way to configure where FreeMarker looks for templates? Using a `@Bean` to produce a `FreeMarkerConfigurer` isn't affecting the configuration at all.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html you can put `spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/template/ # Comma-separated list of template paths.` into your app properties. (or stick with the convention and use `templates` with an s)

Answer (score 0):

http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html

You can put ftl templates inside src/main/resources/templates folder and it will be automatically recognized for free marker version : 2.3.26-incubating in spring boot. Otherwise use the below code in application.properties file and autowire the object where used.

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=relativefolder/
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html